# What's the difference between a file and an attachment when working with iOS App Extensions?

Tags: ios

When building iOS App Extensions there are [several possible keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW10) for `NSExtensionActivationRule` in the plist. What's the difference between `NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount` and `NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount`? How does an "attachment" and a "file" differ in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A File is a physical file in the local file system. Whereas an attachement is a file that is attached to a form of mail, message etc.